# İn which situtations is necessary to retopologize?

Tags: retopology

İn which situtaions should ı retopologize my model?I saw people retopologizing their models just for their character models in the youtube.why?I retopolgize my decorative models too.I'm planning to use these models in a game why others not doing this.İs there a easier way for these models?

Comment: The primary purposes of re-topologizing are to reduce poly count, correct edge flow, and make the mesh properties fit the renderer (es: tri or quad based rendering - blender uses quads). A mesh made of 800,000 verts may be fine on its own if it's going to be duplicated hundred of times in a game engine, it will eventually cost performance - thus, getting the lowest poly count possible is one aim of retopology. Some meshes that are to be animated need certain edge flow (especially around joints) to animate properly. Game engines use tris, but often convert meshes to tris upon import.

Comment: So do I have to retopologize all the models for my game?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things... how detailed is your game? How often are the models used? How large on screen will the models be? How much performance headroom do you have? etc......

Comment: its a large map game and this models will be everywhere ı will use this models  probably often so ı am retopologizin them

Comment: Character models need good topology to animate properly. If a character doesn't have good retopology then there will be a lot of bad deformations when they're animated. When creating high detail character models it would be very hard to rig and animate them due to the high volume of vertices. So we make it easier by bringing that count down and ensuring proper edge flow for good rigging and animation. Static models aren't animated so it's not as important. I always say it's good practice to retopologize because you become better at it and it helps your game a lot. Depending on what it is.

Comment: To answer very directly, it's always necessary to retopologize IF 1) your model must have its poly count reduced (for whatever reason), and 2) your model must be able to deform smoothly during animation. If these two things are both true, you need to retopologize.